# Google TTS <par> tags not working the way as expected

Tags: actions-on-google, google-text-to-speech

I was looking into Google TTS and found the following example with a par tag:

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml#par

In the example, the audio is built properly. There are two sentences and some sounds in the background. However, if you actually use this with their API or the console, it doesn't work. You only get two sentences back and no audio is played. Link to the TTS console:

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech

This is the SSML that I was using:

```
<par>
    <media xml:id="question" begin="0.5s">
      <speak>Who invented the Internet?</speak>
    </media>
    <media xml:id="answer" begin="question.end+2.0s">
      <speak>The Internet was invented by cats.</speak>
    </media>
    <media begin="answer.end-0.2s" soundLevel="-6dB">
      <audio
        src="https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/cartoon/cartoon_boing.ogg"/>
    </media>
    <media repeatCount="3" soundLevel="+2.28dB"
      fadeInDur="2s" fadeOutDur="0.2s">
      <audio
        src="https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/animals/cat_purr_close.ogg"/>
    </media>
  </par>
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is there something wrong with the TTS service itself?

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly something strange about the TTS console, for starters. If you look at the JSON that it says should be used, you'll note that it has omitted the `<par>` tag. Inspecting the network traffic shows the same thing. I also noticed that the `<speech>` tag needed to be omitted.

If you try this as part of the Action Simulator Console, the output does work correctly. You can get to the Action Simulator by going to https://console.actions.google.com/, picking a project to work with, and going to the "Test" tab. In the simulator itself, you then select the "Audio" tab and can enter SSML (including the `<speech>` tag) into the editor and then press the "Update and Listen" button.

[image: illustration of simulator highlighting steps to take]

Comment: Yeah I would not necessarily rely on the widget in the documentation. I have used the actual TTS API with the <par> tag successfully in the past.